# Python post request change date

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to Python and programming, started teaching my self a few months back. I am making a program that is scraping a webpage that uses both json and php, I have scraped the info from the page but there is more info I need and I'm trying to send a post request to change the date that is showing up on the webpage and it's not work. If any one could help.

The webpage snippet looks like:

```html
<div id="cashout_wrap">
<form action="cashout_wrap" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
Date:
<input id="datepicker" name="use_date" style="vertical-align: middle" type="text" value="11/25/2019"/>
```

I want to change the date

The code I'm using is:

```
Html = s.post(URL, data={"value=": "11/22/2019"}, headers=header).content
```

If any one could help me, why the post request is not bring back the date I'm trying to get.

I hope this make sense, I try to figure things out for my self but I've been wracking my brain on this for almost 12 hours now.

Comment: You can try `data={"use_date": "11/22/2019"}` instead `value=`

Comment: Oh yes thank you, that did it. Ty,

Comment: I'll write answer then, so you can accept it and close the question :)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you supply the "wrong" data as post parameters. The correct way should be:

```
Html = s.post(URL, data={"use_date": "11/22/2019"}, headers=header).content
```

Note the `use_date` as key in the dictionary (should match `name=` parameter of the `<input>` tag.